# JBoss EAP 6.4 Jackson module classloading

Tags: jboss, classloader, jboss-eap-6, jboss-modules

I made a small project which looks like this

```
playboss.ear
    lib
        commonlib.jar
            JsonDeserializer.class
        testlib.jar
            JsonMessage.class
            Version.class
        jackson-1.9.4.jar
    playboss_ejb.jar
        MessageTimer.class
```

JsonMessage has a member: *private Class msgVersion = Version.V0.class;
MessageTimer is just a Bean with a timeout which does nothing but deserializes an example String of JsonMessage using JsonDeserializer.
Everything works fine, i.e. the String is converted  to JsonMessage!

Now I add a dependency to my project containing a JAX-RS API and model objects such that lib is extended.

```
    lib
        SomeAPI.jar
        javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar
```

Now when I start the JBoss EAP 6.4  I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: playground.testlib.Version$V0 from [Module "org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl:main" from local module loader @9e89d68
  at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
  at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.ClassDeserializer.deserialize(ClassDeserializer.java:42) [jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.9.redhat-4.jar:1.9.9.redhat-4]
```

I figure that due to https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Implicit+module+dependencies+for+deployments the jax-rs module dependency is triggered and jackson gets loaded from modules.

My questions:
1) What is the recommended / best way to get my deserialization working again
2) I would like to understand how object mapping is done with jax-rs if the module classloader does obviously not see my model classes.